# Функция exp не работает при передаче переменной как аргумента

Tags: c, ubuntu, gcc

Функция exp (expl тоже) работает только при передаче аргумента числовой константой, при передаче аргумента переменной возникает ошибка компиляции:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccKSUeQX.o: в функции «main»:
test.c:(.text+0x1c): неопределённая ссылка на «expl»
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

То есть это работает:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
int main() {
    long double x = 10;
    printf("%Lf\n", expl(10));
}
```

А это нет:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
int main() {
    long double x = 10;
    printf("%Lf\n", expl(x));
}
```

Компилятор:

```
gcc (Ubuntu 11.3.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 11.3.0
Copyright (C) 2021 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

Comment: это работает и это нет содержат одинаковый код

Comment: @Эникейщик, прошу прощения, поправил

Comment: Пишет, что надо Defined in header <tgmath.h>  для этой функции https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/exp и компилировать C99

Comment: @Виктор, к сожалению, не помогло, поведение такое же

Comment: У меня получилось 22026.465795  Language standard: ISO C++

Comment: @Виктор, проблема была в том, что нужно использовать флаг -lm при компиляции
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64568370/why-am-i-getting-undefined-reference-to-sqrt-error-even-though-i-include-math

Comment: при вычислении константы компилятор оптимизирует, используя математическую библиотеку сразу. А вы при сборке не указали эту библиотеку `-lm`. И при отсутствии математической библиотеки появляется ошибка.